# list style menu wordpress style css

Tags: css, list, styles

I loaded directly link to display the menu.
This menu is organized force-lists because it is a wordpress menu levels and sublevels.
Unfortunately, as you can see at the end of the sublayer have a double line.
the effect should be like the first where the link is in two rows.
Can you give me a hint?

http://www.circuitosanmartinodellago.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3's [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alast-child) pseudo-class

```
#menu-main-menu li:last-child {border-bottom:none;}
```

support is good (IE 7/8 not included) http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Comment: Thanks but it must be compatible with IE 7/8 ... Is it possible or impossible mission?
Thanks

Comment: you can use [html5shiv - HTML5 IE enabling script - Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to get CSS3 to work in IE7/8.  For a pure CSS solution that supports old IE you'd have to edit how the menu is rendered to add classes in the last list items

Comment: the last child suggestion is good... I selected the last-child element with jQuery! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So is this being used in wordpress? If thats the case you can apply CSS elements to individual menu items, which wordpress generates by default, which should solve this issue. Just apply your own custom style to that one navigation item such as #menu-item-1.

Comment: It was my first idea but I wanted to find a solution that would also be true for other occasions. Thanks